# Wordpress - site not indexing because of 301 and 302 redirect

Tags: wordpress, indexing, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have a wordpress site: http://davybrown.com that has a 301 and 302 redirect in place. Becuase of this combination, google is not indexing the site. Does anyone know how this is fixed?

I'm running site on wordpress and on a windows(plesk) server.

Thanks